# Why Facebook prompt_feed.php is causing browser window to resize itself

Tags: facebook, sharing

We use Facebook's prompt_feed.php in order to do sharing from a widget.

When we popup a browser window with the sharing URL that uses prompt_feed.php it causes Safari (and in some cases also Firefox) to resize themselves to strange dimensions.

Anyone encountered that? anyone knows how to avoid this?

Thanks
Guy

Comment: Any reason you're not using Facebook Share? http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Share

Comment: as written above "in order to do sharing from a widget". The widget should work standalone without requiring the hosting website to do anything

Answer (score 0):

Please use the Feed Dialog in order to allow a user to share content to Facebook from your site. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

prompt_feed.php is unsupported.